# Frama-c syntax error on macro expansion

Tags: frama-c

I am getting the following syntax error:

```
../stat-time.h:58:[kernel] user error: Cannot find field st_atim
```

This is in the gnu stat-time.h by Paul Eggert. Here's the snippet causing the error:

```
#define STAT_TIMESPEC(st, st_xtim) ((st)->st_xtim)

long int get_stat_atime_ns(struct stat const *st) {
  ...
  // 58:
  return STAT_TIMESPEC(st, st_atim).tv_nsec;
  ...
}
```

I tried to preprocess the file first, then run frama-c on the preprocessed file, but that didn't help. Frama-c still reported the same error at the same location, even though the file was preprocessed correctly and the macro was correctly expanded! I invoked gcc as follows, for preprocessing:

```
gcc -E -C -I. -dD -nostdinc -D__FC_MACHDEP_X86_32 -I/usr/local/share/frama-c/libc
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out the solution. Apparently, the frama-c headers in `/usr/local/share/frama-c/libc/__fc_define_stat.h` lacked the `nsec` granularity fields in `struct stat`. I added the following fields to `struct stat` to fix the problem:

```
    unsigned long int st_atimensec;
    unsigned long int st_mtimensec;
    unsigned long int st_ctimensec;
```

Also, make sure to use the frama-c headers while configuring, e.g., `configure CPP='gcc -E -C -dD -nostdinc -I/usr/local/share/frama-c/libc`. If not, you will need to **undefine** the following two macros: 
`HAVE_STRUCT_STAT_ST_ATIM_TV_NSEC`, `HAVE_STRUCT_STAT_ST_ATIMESPEC_TV_NSEC`, and **define** the following macro: `HAVE_STRUCT_STAT_ST_ATIMENSEC` in a header file, and include it in `config.h` or in `__fc_define_stat.h`